# Show $||f||_p\leq ||f||_\infty$

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, lp-spaces

> On $C([0,1])$ define $||f||_p=(\int_0^1|f(t)|^pdt)^\frac{1}{p}$ for
>   $1\leq p<\infty$ and $||f||_\infty=\sup_{t\in[0,1]}|f(t)|$. Show that
>   $||f||_p\leq ||f||_\infty$

My approach is the following

\begin{align*}
||f||_p^p&=\int_0^1|f(t)|^pdt\\
&\leq|1-0|\cdot\sup_{t\in[0,1]}|f(t)|^p\\
&=(\sup_{t\in[0,1]}|f(t)])^p \\
&=||f||_\infty^p
\end{align*}

However I was told, this is not good enough - that I need to consider some "special case", but I don't see what I need?

Comment: This looks OK. Your best option is to ask the person who made this commentary in the first place. The best thing would have been to ask immediately; don't be afraid, if you don't understand something, don't pretend you understood, ask. (I also pretend that I understood sometimes. It's never good)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is almost correct (except that $\int_0^q$ should be $\int_0^1$). The only problem is that you are acting as if $\lVert f\rVert_\infty=\sup\lvert f\rvert$. Instead, $\lVert f\rVert_\infty$ is the [*essential supremum*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_supremum_and_essential_infimum) of $\lvert f\rvert$. Take that into account.

Comment: The assignment says $f\in C([0,1])$, so that's an actual supremum. It's actually a maximum.

Comment: You are right. I missed that. But then, other than the misprint that I mentioned, the proof is indeed correct.