# Show that $\|f\|_{p}\leq \|f\|_{\infty}$ for any $0<p<\infty$ in a general measure space $X$ with $\mu(X)=1$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Consider a general measure space $(\mu, \Sigma,X)$ with $\mu(X)=1$. I want to show that for any $\mu-$measurable function and for any $0<p<\infty$, we have $$\|f\|_{p}\leq \|f\|_{\infty}.$$

A similar question is here [Show $||f||_p\leq ||f||_\infty$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3035164/show-f-p-leq-f-infty), but it is in an easier case, in the space $C([0,1])$, it seems that the $\sup-$norm is the same as the $\sup_{x}|f(x)|$. However, in a general measure space, the $\sup-$norm is actually an essential $\sup$: $$\|f\|_{\infty}=\inf\{M\geq 0:|f(x)|\leq M\ \text{holds for almost every}\ x\}.$$

Thus, the only thing I know is that $|f(x)|\leq\|f\|_{\infty}$ $\mu-$almost surely. I want to start from here but I got stuck:

We have $|f(x)|^{p}\leq\|f\|_{\infty}^{p}$ $\mu-$almost surely, and thus the set defined by $E:=\{x\in X:|f(x)|^{p}>\|f\|_{\infty}^{p}\}$ has $\mu(E)=0$.

Now, $$\int_{X}|f^{p}(x)|\mu(dx)\leq \int_{X\setminus E}|f(x)|^{p}\mu(dx)+\int_{E}|f(x)|^{p}\mu(dx).$$

The first integral is easy to evaluate, since $\mu(X)=1$, we know that $\mu(X\setminus E)=1$, and thus $$\int_{X\setminus E}|f(x)|^{p}\mu(dx)\leq \int_{X\setminus E}\|f\|_{\infty}^{p}\mu(dx)=\|f\|^{p}_{\infty}\mu(X\setminus E)=\|f\|^{p}_{\infty}.$$

But how to evaluate the second integral? Over $E$ I just have a reversed directly $>$. I have no idea how to bound it..

Thank you for any help!!

Comment: Integral of any measurable function over a set of measure $0$ is $0$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy ah.... how could I forget this.......

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thank you so much! Yeah.. I can actually prove this. Let me answer my own question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. Sorry for the stupid question. As the comment suggested, the integral of any measurable function over a zero measure set is $0$.

Indeed, one could see here [Integral over null set is zero](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/293801/integral-over-null-set-is-zero).